# Pygame simple issue, object movement and display

Tags: python, pygame

```
    player_1 = pygame.image.load(player1)
    #

    def player1(x,y):
        window.blit(player_1, (x,y))

    x =  (110)
    y = (150)
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0
    player1_speed = 0

    while not gameover:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               gameover = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
               elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                  x_change = 5

               elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                  y_change = -5

              elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                 y_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            x_change = 0


        x += x_change
        y += y_change        

        player1(x,y)
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(60)
        screen.blit(background_surface, (0,0))

# update display
pygame.display.flip()
```

Hi, I have a program where unfortunatley when moving the object, it moves left & right perfectly but up and down does not seem to stop. There is also an issue of the screen flashing. Sorry for the long question but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You only reset `x_change` on keyup...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I repair where should I put it, an any reason why the screen flashes, I think it is something to do with  screen.blit(background_surface, (0,0))

Answer (score 1):

**1.** As far as I see you are only blitting player1. Where is player2?

**2.** You are missing some indentation in your code. I guess the correct form would be:

```
 if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        x_change = 0
```

**3.** Then your are only setting x_change to 0. I guess you want to set y_change to 0 as well... even though you have to make your query more specific by grouping up vertical and horizontal keys.

Like:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    x_change = 0
if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
    y_change = 0
```

**4.** You call the blit method after updating the screen. Moving pygame.display.update() after screen.blit(..) would fix some things...

**5.** The flip method is outside of your loop. It will only be called if your game loop breaks!

Little hint: Copy-Pasting is a very bad practice. Try to do it yourself instead!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, after placing pygame.displau.update() after screen.blit... , the player dosen't seem to show at all.

Comment: Maybe thats because you are blitting him to window which isnt even mentioned in your supplied code ^^

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean,  player_1 = pygame.image.load(player1)
 is this wrong?

    def player1(x,y):
        window.blit(player_1, (x,y))

Comment: window.blit(player_1, (x,y)) - you have not supplied code for the window surface.

Comment: oh sorry,  window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))

Comment: Why do you use window AND screen then? Lets say we ignore screen for now and use window instead -> you call the method window.blit(background_surface..) and then player(x,y). After that you are free to call the pygame.display.flip() method

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but very confused, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @rogersinclair If you would have just read the pygame documentation this would not be a problem.